# JPA unidirectional one-to-many association "A Foreign key refering [entity] has the wrong number of column"

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I have these two tables:

WorkPlace table:

- userId - primary key, foreign key
- organization - primary key, foreign key
- unit - primary key, foreign key
- //other non relevant fields (room, status etc...)

Users table:

- userId - primary key
- //other non relevant fields (sex, email etc...)

As the above tables show, i have many users, and each user has one workplace. A user does not have a reference to the workplace (as it should be after some reading), but the workplace has references to the users. I can't change the database design, so I have to make it work like this. So in order to map this, I have the following code in my workplace entity:

```
@OneToMany//(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="userId")
private Set<User> users;
```

The attribute of join column is the foreign key identifier of the users in the WorkPlace table. For this i get the following error:

```
"A Foreign key refering hu.danubius.doclams.be.entity.org.UsersWork from hu.danubius.doclams.be.entity.org.User has the wrong number of column. should be 3"
```

I gather that the program needs to reference the WorkPlace entity's primary key, but I don't understand why, or how could I resolve this. What am I missing?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What's UsersWork and how it's related with Users and WorkPlace?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I wasn't clear. UsersWork is the WorkPlace entity.

Answer (score 0):

For your entities, see [Java EE 6 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) on `JoinColumn` for an example on how to use it.

Since you didn't show all parts of the entity and the according database structure, I may only guess that you don't use the correct database column for mapping - is `userId` really the name of the column in the table holding the ID of an User?

Comment: I'm not sure i quite understand what you're saying.

A User entity has only a simple primary key (userId), and that's the field that is referenced from WorkPlace table (UsersWork entity - sorry for the confusion).

Comment: Yes it is "sadly"... I'm just gonna use native queries and I won't use associations.

Comment: @Tsohun: do you have many to one mapping in user entity? Provide code or we can't help...

Comment: I don't have that. That's only for bi-directional associations, no? Anyway it seems that I've managed to solve it with native queries, so thank you for your time!
Also, sorry for the late responses, but it seems that we have a big difference in our timezones, and I go to bed about the time you responde.